# What's mac software is available to create videos like the squareup.com intro video?

Tags: macos, video, editing, final-cut-pro

This is a somewhat famous video now: https://squareup.com/intro

What mac software is available to easily create these effects?  Could it be done with iMovie or do you need something like FinalCut?

Comment: This is an ancient question, but as a software request, it's now off-topic.  It looks like you never got a satisfactory answer, and the link is dead so it can't be answered now.  Without the link, it's also not much use to other readers.  Rather than closing it or investing time to fix it, would you consider just deleting it?

Answer (score 0):

iMovie can’t do all those transformations. You will need Final Cut Express. I think that they aren’t doing anything that Express can’t do. But you might want to check first. Of course you’ll need the appropriate equipment to record all that material in the first place. But if you had the footage, it could be done with FCE.